# ¿Cómo añadir la carpeta "webapp" o la característica de Java Server Faces a proyecto maven en Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

¿Cómo añado esta característica a mi proyecto maven en Intellij IDEA?

1. Click derecho sobre el proyecto.
2. Propiedades.
3. Ir a "project faces".
4. Añadir "JavaServer Faces".

De tal manera que crea la carpeta `webapp-WEB-INF` y dos archvivos dentro (`web.xml` y `faces-config.xml`).

¿Cómo hago estos pasos en Intellij IDEA?

Comment: Hola @AndresFranco, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.